# Stacking Landsat 8 bands using semi-classification plugin?

Tags: qgis, landsat

I am currently using the exercise titled [Supervised Land Cover Classification Exercise 1](https://arset.gsfc.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/land/webinars/Advanced_Land_Classification/supervised_exercise_v2.pdf)

After I have created the individual band sets using the pre-processing tool, the next step in the exercise (see link above) requires to stack the bands together using the band set icon in SCP. My bands 2-7 were in the band set definition box, (in tandem with the above exercise) but when I click to 'create raster of band set (stack bands)' and run it (in band set icon of SCP plugin), I get a completely pitch black Bstack_raster.tif image. I have tried changing the color style under the properties table but it still remains pitch black. I have tried backtracking to see any mistake but as far as I can see I have followed the correct procedure in the exercise.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on p4? "In order to display this image in a usable color combination, go to the Layers
Panel and right click on the stacked raster image. Go to Properties and select
Style. Put band 5 in the red band, band 4 in the green band and band 3 in the
blue band, and make sure Contrast enhancement is set to “Stretch to MinMax”.
In the section “Load min/max values” to the right, click Load, and then click OK."

Comment: Yes I did.in short every step in that document, I followed to the letter.in my case,in the multiband section, there are no values since the image is just black.

Comment: Just to help you,the image I used,I downloaded it from Glovis website-Landsat 8 OLI, path 43,row 33:date is September 22nd,2015. Be assured all instructions at pg 4 & before were followed to the letter.

Comment: Just download the above image (using info given)unzip it,you can use 7-zip extractor, perform the actions on it using SCP as per the instructions on pg 1-4 of the exercise. Feedback will be appreciated. In short I followed everything, until this unusual result.

Comment: My values in the style properties section, for [min]in the three bands they all read nan,i n short,I tried changing style using those same instructions but not successful